# Implicit conversion from null

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Looking Zoran Horvats courses at PluralSight, I'm currently implementing a Maybe type, a bit like Zoran has on its GitHub account: https://github.com/zoran-horvat/option

Generally, a Maybe is a wrapper around objects, which are either set or have a null value, avoiding null reference exceptions.
To make the code a bit shorter, I would like to use implicit conversion to map the values / nulls to their corresponding maybe types. Here an example of my code:

```
    public void Hook(Maybe<Action<Keys>> onKeyDown, Maybe<Action<Keys>> onKeyUp)
    {
        _keyDownCallback = onKeyDown;
        _keyUpCallback = onKeyUp;

        _hookService.Hook(HookType.KeyBoardLowLevel, OnHookReceived);
    }
```

As you can see, you can hook and pass two optional callbacks, one for keyDown and one for keyUp. I would like to pass code like this:

```
nativeKeyboardHookService.Hook(new Action<Keys>(OnNativeKeyDown), null);
```

The implicit conversion on the Maybe is currently implemented like this:

```
    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value)
    {
        return ToMaybe(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Maybe<T> maybe)
    {
        return ToT(maybe);
    }

    public static Maybe<T> ToMaybe(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new None<T>();
        }

        return new Some<T>(value);
    }

    public static T ToT(Maybe<T> maybe)
    {
        return maybe.Evaluate(
            value => value,
            () => default(T));
    }
```

My question: It works fine, if I pass an actual object, mapping it to an Maybe, but if I pass NULL, I still get a NULL object, not a None object. Am I doing here something wrong or is it just not possible? I didn't find any further information regarding such a conversion.

Comment: `but if I pass NULL` <= pass `null` to what exactly? To `ToMaybe` or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `null` to `Hook()` that's literally all you are doing because your implicit casts aren't being invoked at all. That's because `null` is a valid value for a reference type, and thus no need to cast.

You can't change `Maybe` to a struct if you want to keep `Some` and `None` because then these would have to be structs too, which means you run into the issue that you can't inherit structs.

You can't implement a common `IMaybe<T>` interface either because interfaces can't be used with casts.

What I recommend is keep your behavior as is, but don't use `null`. Instead of passing `null`, pass something else like `Maybe<T>.None`:

```
class Maybe<T>
{
    public static Maybe<T> None { get; } = new None<T>();
}

void Hook(..., Maybe<T>.None) { ... }
```

Or `None<T>.Instance`:

```
class None<T>
{
    public static None<T> Instance{ get; } = new None<T>();
}

void Hook(..., None<T>.Instance) { ... }
```

This has the advantage of being more readable and explicit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already had a feeling this won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Maybe<T>` is still a reference type, so `null` is a valid value for it:

```
Maybe<string> foo = null;
```

If you want to prevent that, you will need to make it a value type, for example something like this:

```
public struct Maybe<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public bool IsEmpty => Value == null;

    public Maybe(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Then you can pass `null` to a method expecting a `Maybe<T>` and it will properly construct an empty `Maybe<T>` object.

But note that it being a value type, this now means that it is copied on every method call, so it has a different behavior to a reference type implementation.

In the end, you cannot really implement this nicely in C# simply because there *is* the null reference in the language. It’s only with C# 8’s nullable reference types that you will be able to prevent nulls altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll go with a factory method then.